# How to debug react on apache server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apache

A react app that uses React Router has been deployed on an apache server. The .htaccess file has been modified and most of the routes work as intended.

Some routes depend on a selection that the user has made. The selection is stored locally using localStorage and shared in the app through a context. However, those routes return an error:

```
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

When the app is deployed locally(npm start) or via PaaS(netlify etc) everything works as they should. The error only occurs on apache

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FallbackResource` under the `<Directory>` or `<VirtualHost>` configuration to serve index.html for all URLs that do not map to anything.

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

Comment: The routes exist in the router(they are mapped) but they still don't work

Comment: @KonstantinidisKonstantinos And setting a FallbackResource also doesn't work?